# need to populate an array in php with urls as key

Tags: php, arrays, url, multidimensional-array

I need an Array of the following structure:

```
Array
(
[www.example.com] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://www.example.com/
        [1] => http://www.example.com/something.html
        [2] => http://www.example.com/anything.html
    )

[www.beispiel.com] => Array
    (
        [0] => http://www.beispiel.com/product-services/
        [1] => http://www.beispiel.com/non-disclosure-agreement/
    )
 )
```

As input arrays I have the following two

```
Array ( [0] => http://www.example.com/
        [1] => http://www.example.com/something.html
        [2] => http://www.example.com/anything.html
        [3] => http://www.beispiel.com/product-services/
        [4] => http://www.beispiel.com/non-disclosure-agreement/
      )
```

and

```
Array ( [0] => www.example.com [1] => www.beispiel.com )
```

in the moment I have something like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [www.example.com] => http://www.example.com/
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [www.example.com] => http://www.example.com/something.html
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [www.example.com] => http://www.example.com/anything.html
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [www.beispiel.com] => http://www.beispiel.com/product-services/
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [www.beispiel.com] => http://www.beispiel.com/non-disclosure-agreement/
    )

)
```

is that possible or do I miss some information about php (for example key could not be an parsed url (host)) ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you have to try something.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to get the hostname from the URL.  Look at the `parse_url` function in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$arr1 = array('http://www.example.com/','http://www.example.com/something.html','http://www.beispiel.com/product-services/' ...); // 1st input array
$arr2 = array('www.example.com', 'www.beispiel.com'); // 2nd input array
$arr1_val = array_values($arr1);
foreach($arr2 as $v) {
 foreach($arr1 as $m) {       
   if(strpos($m, $v) !== FALSE)
    $new_arr[$v][] = $m;
  }      
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/fjL2ZDlK)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Same naming rules apply for array keys, as it does for variables.